# Configuring larswm to use touchpad in Debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, touchpad, window-manager

I have probably a rather strange taste regarding window managers but the best one I have found so far is larswm. Although it is available in Debian Wheezy, making it useable involves a bit of system configuration. Most importantly in Debian touchpad support is handled by Gnome by default and is not available in when larswm is used. What would be the recommended Debian way to enable touchpad support without Gnome? I'm using Samsung 400B4B.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out it's enough to put the following

```
 Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "Touchpad"                      # required
        MatchIsTouchpad "yes"                           # required
        Driver          "synaptics"                     # required
        Option          "MinSpeed"              "0.5"
        Option          "MaxSpeed"              "1.0"
        Option          "AccelFactor"           "0.075"
        Option          "TapButton1"            "1"
        Option          "TapButton2"            "2"     # multitouch
        Option          "TapButton3"            "3"     # multitouch
        Option          "VertTwoFingerScroll"   "1"     # multitouch
        Option          "HorizTwoFingerScroll"  "1"     # multitouch
        Option          "VertEdgeScroll"        "1"
        Option          "CoastingSpeed"         "8"
        Option          "CornerCoasting"        "1"
        Option          "CircularScrolling"     "1"
        Option          "CircScrollTrigger"     "7"
        Option          "EdgeMotionUseAlways"   "1"
        Option          "LBCornerButton"        "8"     # browser "back" btn
        Option          "RBCornerButton"        "9"     # browser "forward" btn
   EndSection
```

into /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/synaptics.conf

(or any other filename you prefer in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d )